# How to return drupal's articles image upload

Tags: nodes, media

I am new in drupal

when I click on content>add content
I don't have the browse button to uploading image for article, maybe I removed accidentally from structure>content type or other...

How can I see that browse button again?

Comment: Add image filed again to that content type.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: @Kermani https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/field-ui

Comment: @Kermani FYI, Posted answer

Comment: @Krishna Mohan, ok, I will check it as my answer, please vote up this answer becuse stackexchange dont let the vote down answer to ask question again

Comment: @Kermani We don't have automatic question bans here; but you wouldn't get banned for a single downvote on a single question anywhere in the network, even Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Clive But it's a long time that I am banned in stack overflow because down vote, and after that I answered some question but I am ban Yet

Comment: This isn't Stack Overflow, it's a separate website with separate data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Structure » Content types » Article >> Manage fileds

Add new field. Here is the sample screenshot

[image]